# Counting SQL Server results

Tags: sql-server

I want to `COUNT(*)` how many rows there is in `Offer` table if it has it's counterpart in `Product` table having `Product.Producer` column equal to `123` and `Offer.PricePolicy` column is `31`.

This query returns 3 results:

```
# | ID
----------
1 | 1277
2 | 1279
2 | 1280
```

How to modify it to return number of results?

Expected result is `3`

```
SELECT Product.ID
FROM Offer
LEFT JOIN Product ON Offer.ID = Product.ID
WHERE Product.Producer = 123
  AND Offer.PricePolicy = 31
GROUP BY Product.ID
```

Comment: `SELECT
    COUNT(*)...` instead of `SELECT
    Product.ID...`!? Maybe I misunderstood your question, but if you just want to have the number of results then you should use COUNT(*) - but that was already posted in your question, so I am somewhat confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `COUNT(*)` to the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT Product.ID, COUNT(*)
FROM Offer
LEFT JOIN Product ON Offer.ID = Product.ID
WHERE Product.Producer = 123
AND Offer.PricePolicy = 31
GROUP BY Product.ID
```

If you do not need the `Product.ID`, you can only have `COUNT(*)` in the projection as well.

Comment: it returns same number multiple times. Is `DISTINCT(COUNT(*)) AS COUNTED` ok? It works but is it the right thing to do?

Comment: Count(Distinct ProductID) or put column whatever you want to calculate.. You can use this when you want to calculate count of distinct value

Comment: What do you mean with "it returns same number multiple times"? Do you only have `COUNT(*)` in your projection? If one number appears more often, that means there are several products matching the query and you get a result for each of them. Try both `Product.ID` and `COUNT(*)` in your query to see the difference.

Comment: @WeSt SanjayGoswami comment is ok for me